# My app deployed in Heroku.com is not working

Tags: node.js, reactjs, heroku, react-router

I deployed an application on Heroku.com for CI/CD. I deployed the app in June, however the link is no more active.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a54qf.png)

I bought the Heroku monthly subscription yesterday, however not able to view my application still.

Comment: Stackoverflow isn't a support platform or forum, so this question isn't really on-topic here. You may need to work through Heroku's support channels to get help with accessing your deployed application.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. [HTTP 500](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#5xx_server_errors) is a generic server-side error message. On its own it doesn't tell us anything useful. Any time you see this your first step should be to check your error logs for more detail. On Heroku, you can do this by running [`heroku logs`](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli-commands#heroku-logs).

Answer (score 1):

First thing to do is to check the logs by clicking the **View Logs** from the dropdown of the **More** options on the top right of your app overview page.

If you have previously deployed apps, you can still access them after the subscription. If the log shows an **H14 error**, try to **reconfigure your dyno**. Just change your dyno type to the subscribed plan and make sure you have toggle the selected dyno to the right in order to enable it.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for suggesting this @Ethan, let me try this solution.

Comment: If this suggestion worked for you, it is useful to all users (including yourself) to "accept" the answer (only you can do this by the way) see: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers